# AutoFilter with an array of numbers as a criteria

Tags: arrays, vba, numbers, criteria, autofilter

I am using the code below to filter a certain column. I want to select all positive numbers and negative numbers: -1, -2, -3. Criteria1 is working but in criteria2, I only get rows with -3. I can't make the array with negative numbers work. Help please.

```
With Range("A:AG")
     .AutoFilter Field:=33, Criteria:=">0", Operator:=xlOr, _
     Criteria2:=Array("-1", "-2", "-3"), Operator:= xlFilterValues
End With
```

Comment: Couldn't get away with 1 criteria? ie. `>= -3`? And if you want to exclude `0` just add that as a second one

Comment: @mehow I didn't realize how simple this was. `Criteria2:=">= -3"` did it for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2140173/me-how

`With Range("A:AG")
     .AutoFilter Field:=33, Criteria:=">0", Operator:=xlOr, _
     Criteria2:=">= -3", Operator:= xlFilterValues
End With`